# Failing test with message 'OTransitionProperty'

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I trying to run jest test on react app without --env=jsdom. Problem is that I mock all information in setupTests.js but still something is missing. At the moment when running test getting error:

```
TypeErrorL Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'OTransitionProperty' in undefined
```

Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: to know what you need to mock, you are going to have to provide the piece of code that references OTransitionProperty

Comment: it's probably a style object. Why do you run it without --env=jsdom?

Comment: As documentation is saying it is faster and not really needed when I'm not using for example mount only shallow with snapshot

Comment: I'm using also css-js which wrapped component in withStyles but only component is tested and I pass theme trough context